# Verifying programs with heterogeneous arrays in VST

Tags: coq, verifiable-c

I'm verifying a c program that uses arrays to store heterogeneous data - in particular, the program uses arrays to implement cons cells, where the first element of the array is an integer value, and the second element is a pointer to the next cons cell.

For example, the free operation for this list would be:

```
void listfree(void * x) {
  if((x == 0)) {
    return;
  } else {
    void * n = *((void **)x + 1);
    listfree(n);
    free(x);
    return;
  }
}
```

Note: Not shown here, but other code sections will read the values of the array and treat it as an integer.

While I understand that the natural way to express this would be as some kind of struct, the program itself is written using an array, and I can't change this.

How should I specify the structure of the memory in VST?

I've defined an `lseg` predicate as follows:

```
Fixpoint lseg (x: val) (s: (list val)) (self_card: lseg_card) : mpred := match self_card with
    | lseg_card_0  =>  !!(x = nullval) && !!(s = []) && emp
    | lseg_card_1 _alpha_513 => 
      EX v : Z,
      EX s1 : (list val),
      EX nxt : val,
 !!(~ (x = nullval)) && 
   !!(s = ([(Vint (Int.repr v))] ++ s1)) && 
   (data_at Tsh (tarray tint 2) [(Vint (Int.repr v)); nxt] x) * 
   (lseg nxt s1 _alpha_513)
end.
```

However, I run into troubles when trying to evaluate `void *n = *(void **)x;` presumably because the specification states that the memory contains an array of ints not pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably as follows, and can *almost* be solved as follows.

The C semantics permit casting an integer (of the right size) to a pointer, and vice versa, as long as you don't actually do any pointer operations to an integer value, or vice versa.  Very likely your C program obeys those rules.  But the type system of Verifiable C tries to enforce that local variables (and array elements, etc.) of integer type will never contain pointer values, and vice versa (except the special integer value 0, which is NULL).

However, Verifiable C does support a (proved-foundationally-sound) workaround to this stricter enforcement:

```
typedef void  * int_or_ptr
 #ifdef COMPCERT
   __attribute((aligned(_Alignof(void*))))
 #endif
  ;
```

That is: the `int_or_ptr` type is `void*`, but with the attribute "align this as `void*`".  So it's semantically identical to `void*`, but the redundant attribute is a hint to the VST type system to be less restrictive about C type enforcement.

So, when I say "can *almost* be solved", I'm asking:  Can you modify the C program to use an array of "void* aligned as void*"  ?

If so, then you can proceed.  Your VST verification should use `int_or_ptr_type`, which is a definition of type `Ctypes.type` provided by VST-Floyd, when referring to the C-language type of these array elements, or of local variables that these elements are loaded into.

Unfortunately, int_or_ptr_type is not documented in the reference manual (VC.pdf), which is an omission that should be correct.  You can look at progs/int_or_ptr.c and progs/verif_int_or_ptr.v, but these do *much* more than you want or need:  They axiomatize operators that distinguish odd integers from aligned pointers, which is undefined in C11 (but consistent with C11, otherwise the ocaml garbage collector could never work).  That is, those axiomatized external functions are consistent with CompCert, gcc, clang;  but you won't need any of them, because the only operations you're doing on int_or_pointer are the perfectly-legal "comparison with NULL" and "cast to integer" or "cast to `struct foo *`".